# EntLib 6 and ODP.NET - Accessor loses parameters

Tags: c#, oracle, enterprise-library, odp.net, daab

I'm sure I can't be the first one trying to use EntLib 6's Accessors to execute an Oracle SP with parameters. It all worked fine and dandy when I was using the (deprecated) OracleClient from MS, but when I switched to Oracle's own ODP.NET (using EntLibContrib 6) I started getting the infamous *"wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TEST_PROCEDURE'"*.

Here's my code:

**Main**

```
var query = "TEST_PROCEDURE";

var accessor = _db.CreateSprocAccessor(
    query, 
    new OracleParamMapper(),
    new ColumnMapper<MyEntity>().Map()
);

var p1 = new OracleParameter("param1", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 1);
p1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
p1.Value = "T";

var p2 = new OracleParameter("param2", OracleDbType.RefCursor);
p2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

return accessor.Execute(p1, p2);
```

**OracleParamMapper**

```
public class OracleParamMapper : IParameterMapper
{
    public void AssignParameters(DbCommand command, object[] parameterValues)
    {
        ((OracleCommand)command).BindByName = true;

        foreach (var item in parameterValues)
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

**This mapper gets invoked,** and I can see the parameters being correctly added to the collection, but then for some misterious reason they seem to disappear when the call to Execute is made.

**Stored Procedure**

```
PROCEDURE TEST_PROCEDURE (param1  IN VARCHAR2, param2  IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR);
```

Has anyone been able to make this work? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's working now. In fact the answer was right there this whole time. All I had to do was to use the classes provided by the **EntLibContrib** library and voila!

In case anyone reads this, just take a look at the `CreateOracleSprocAccessor()` method in the `EntLibContrib.Data.OdpNet.OracleDatabase` class. Cheers!